Problema de importación en node.js usando type:module
Estoy intentando importar ficheros en node.js y tengo definido en package.json el parámetro type:module, antes usaba require pero en este caso al usar type:module, ya no es posible y por tanto lo estoy haciendo de esta manera.
node --version
v20.2.0
package.json
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mssql": "^10.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.2"
  },
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib"
  }
}

A continuación un ejemplo muy sencillo que falla al importar Test. Cuando importo Test, para hacer las pruebas falla. Realmente es Usuario lo que quiero importar pero para ponerlo más claro.
auth.controller.js
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

//import Usuario from '../models/user/Usuario';
import Test from '../models/user/Test';


export const register = async (req, res) => {
    //db operations
   

};

Y a continuación la definición de una clase muy simple que sirve de ejemplo:
Test.js
export default class Test {

}

y el error:
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/david/proyectos-react/backend/models/user/Test' imported from /Users/david/proyectos-react/backend/controllers/auth.controller.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:226:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:839:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1069:11)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:305:12)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:156:32)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:33)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Actualización:
Añado imagen con la estructura:


Estaría bien que pusieras un desglose de tus archivos para saber si el archivo que estás tratando de importar está en la ruta correcta. Pero creo que es porque tienes que utilizar ./models en lugar de ../models

Ya lo he probado y en principio no va

Por lo que tengo entendido. Solamente es cuestión de que agregues ".js" al archivo que estás importando, sino no lo va a tomar como una importación.
